# JAXB Reuse same object in different root elements

Tags: jaxb

I'm trying to convert an xml into java objects and using JAXB for same.
the contents of xml file :

```
<root1>
    <element attr='attr-value1'>
      <child>some-value1</child>
    </element>
</root1>
<root2>
    <element attr='attr-value2'>
      <child>some-value2</child>
    </element>
</root2>
```

I've created a class for "element". Since the child object is same for both root1 and root2, i dont want to create separate classes for both. what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

**You can have multiple roots in your project with the same type in it.**

Here's an example :

**Root1.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root1")
public class Root1 {

  @XmlElement(name="element")
  protected Element element;
}
```

**Root2.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root2")
public class Root2 {

  @XmlElement(name="element")
  protected Element element;
}
```

**Element.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
  ...
})
public class Element {
  ...
}
```

### EDIT

You have no choice to have 2 seperate classes but you can use inheritance.

**Example with inheritance :**

**Root.java**

```
public class Root {

  @XmlElement(name="element")
  protected Element element;
}
```

**Root1.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root1")
public class Root1 extends Root {
  // Here Element is inherited from Root class
  // So you don't need to declare it
}
```

**Root2.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root2")
public class Root2 extends Root {
  // Here Element is inherited from Root class
  // So you don't need to declare it
}
```

**Element.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
  ...
})
public class Element {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid 2 separate classes : Root1.java and Root2.java?

Comment: Actually there are many such root elements in my xml . Thats why looking for a way by which i can assign multiple root element names to one class. thanks for your suggestion!